# Visual Studio and .NET Framework 4.6.2

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-framework-version

I have an issue with Visual Studio 2017 and some my projects. I've already installed `.NET Frameowrk 4.6.2` in my machine and rebooted it. Although, when I open a solution in Visual Studio, I receive this message.

What can I do? Thank you in advance

[image: Visual Studio 2017]

Comment: Did you install 4.6.2 developer pack (sdk), and not just the runtime?

Comment: Have your restarted your machine after installation?

Comment: Yes, it is my answer for both

Answer (score 0):

Just faced with the same problem and it appeared that by navigating via visual studio suggestion to download .NET Framework 4.6.2 developer pack, it downloads your local language pack (in my case it was RUS). The pack that you need actually should be ENU. And looks like the only way to download it, is to find somewhere direct link on it (Like this: https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/F/D/EFD52638-B804-4865-BB57-47F4B9C80269/NDP462-DevPack-KB3151934-ENU.exe).